# Sending bulk emails with MailKit using a throttle fails with a delay of 10 seconds or more

Tags: c#, async-await, amazon-ses, mailkit, mimekit

I am using a loop to send bulk emails via MailKit with an added throttle (delay). The idea is that I intend to send a limit of 20 individual emails per second to multiple recipients. To throttle the sends, I have added a Task.Delay (e.g. `int delay = 1000 / 20` ) inside the loop.

We are using an ESP with 40 sends per second (AWS SES), so it is definitely not the SMTP server.

This seems to work well except when I tried testing it with a delay of 10 seconds or more. I stress, I'm testing only.

Here is my test sender:

```
    protected void Send( )
    {
        var messages = new List<MimeMessage>( );

        for( int i = 1; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage
            {
                Sender = new MailboxAddress( "Sender Name", "Sender Email Address" ),
                Subject = "Test email " + i.ToString( ),
                Body = new TextPart( TextFormat.Html ) { Text = "Test body " + i.ToString( ) }
            };
            message.To.Add( new MailboxAddress( "test" + i.ToString( ) + "@example.com" ) );
            messages.Add( message );
        }

        MailNew.SendMultipleAsyncMails( messages );
    }
```

Here is the sender code:

```
    public static void SendMultipleAsyncMails( List<MimeMessage> messages )
    {
        Task t = Task.Run( async ( ) =>
        {
            using( var client = new SmtpClient( ) )
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync( "Host", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls );
                await client.AuthenticateAsync( "UserName", "Password" );
                foreach( var message in messages )
                {
                    await client.SendAsync( message );
                    await Task.Delay( 10000 );
                }
                await client.DisconnectAsync( true );
            }
        } );
    }
```

What happens is it throws an exception of: `'MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException' in mscorlib.dll` after the first send if there is a delay of 10 seconds or more. I can't see why this should make a difference.

Realistically, you would never add a delay of 10 seconds or more to this process, but I am asking out of curiosity as to why it does this and to confirm that I have not missed anything important.

Can anyone work out why a 10+ second delay will fail?

Comment: Remember, it fails after the first send, so it is not too many sends or connections to the SMTP server.

Comment: What does the protocol log look like? https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog

Comment: `after the first send if there is a delay of 10 seconds or more.` So a delay of 5 seconds works fine? But not 10 or 15 seconds?

Comment: Absolutely. Anything up to 9.5 seconds always works. 9.999 fails. 10+ seconds fails.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the `SendAsync` fails *before* the first invocation of `Task.Delay`? In other words: does this loop fail the first time through the loop? Or does it fail during some later iteration?

Comment: What's the actual exception message?

Comment: Firstly, the debug tells me nothing except the ```'MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException' in mscorlib.dll```. I am not the greatest at debugging, but I've tried everything I know to extract more debug info. Secondly, Send behaves the same as SendAsync. It occurs around 9.6+ seconds. Thirdly, the SendAsync fails after the first ```Task.Delay```.

I wonder if the AWS SES server closes the connection after inactivity of 9-10 seconds? I used ```client.IsConnected``` to test connectivity and it is always true.

Comment: `client.IsConnected` will always return true until an error reading or writing to the socket occurs. But of course, if an error reading or writing to the socket occurs, you get an exception. In other words, you cannot rely on that property until you get an exception. As far as what @Tyddlywink was asking: what is `ex.Message`? That's more useful than just knowing the type of the exception. The `ex.StackTrace` property would also be useful in most cases.

Comment: `try { await client.SendAsync( message );
                    await Task.Delay( 10000 );} catch (exception ex){ var me =ex;}` wrap your Sending code in a try catch and drop a breakpoints on the `var me = ex;` what is the value of me.message and the stacktrace

Comment: Okay, I'll investigate the exception and provide more details. Just to confirm, the exception occurs on the second pass when it hits ```await client.SendAsync( message );```.

Comment: Using the debug output window in VS2019, all I get is:

```'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132077169413922225): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0xb78c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb1a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).```

Comment: I have tried (many times before) to wrap the code inside a try catch using: 

```catch( Exception ex ) { var error = ex.Message; var st = ex.StackTrace; }```

... and it never reaches the catch. In fact, the debug never stops the application running. I can continue on as if nothing ever went wrong.

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast for the tip on the protocol logger. I have tested 9 seconds - perfect. As soon as I use 10 seconds, the log shows the following after the first send:

```S: 451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.
C: RSET```

Can you elaborate on where this might be coming from?  Is this from the mail server?

Comment: Okay, found the issue. It's AWS SES. The email server responded with the following error code
 
```451 Timeout waiting for data from client
Too much time elapsed between requests, so the SMTP server closed the connection.```

This now makes sense as to why there was no exception in the code, but it's interesting that application continued to run as if there was no issue.

Comment: `I have tried (many times before) to wrap the code inside a try catch using` Please show us how you wrote the `try catch` (since it should work). Also, great work solving your issue. In terms of the downvote - the culprit is very unlikely to explain why they downvoted. They are likely long gone.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills. To be honest, I was hoping you guys knew of another level of debugging that I was not familiar with. This was an assumption on my part because I am very familiar with using a try catch to examine an exception. Since there wasn't any caught exception I was thinking "maybe there's a deeper level of debugging that I have never used and everyone else knows about it!?" Hence my inability to provide an exception message. We live and learn. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it all worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found the issue. It's AWS SES. The email server responded with the following error code:

> 451 Timeout waiting for data from client
>   Too much time elapsed between requests, so the SMTP server closed the connection.

This now makes sense as to why there was no exception in the code, but it's interesting that application continued to run as if there was no issue.

The only way to trace this error was to use the protocol log as suggested by @jstedfast